# Adding a matching image to a random message | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently trying to code a Discord bot that will output a recommended anime show by picking a choice from a data table or string. I already did that part, but I cannot figure out how to add an image that matches the show. Here is the code I currently have. (for one genre)

```
bot.on('message', message => {

let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch (args[0]) {

    case 'Action':


        let actions = ['show1',
            'show2',
            'show3',
            'show4',
            'show5',
            'show6',
            'show7',
            'show8',
        ];
       
        let pick1 = actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)];
        const action = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Reccommended Action Anime:')
            .setDescription(actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)])
        message.author.send(action);

        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to use an object for each show, which has a title and an image (some url to a picture in some image cloud service like IMGur or else)

```
    let actions = [
        {'name': 'show1', 'image': 'https://i.imgur.com/ktEA3WS.png'},
        {'name': 'show2', 'image': 'https://i.imgur.com/zcbnc6g.png'},
        ...
    ]
```

You can set the random like this:

```
const randomShow = actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)]
```

And then you just set the description and the image using the object properties.

```
.setDescription(randomShow.name)  // I don't know how to set images in discord but should be similar
```